# WMI Access Denied using Windows 2008 connecting to Windows 2003

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, wmi

I'm trying to connect from a Windows 2008 server to Windows 2003 using WMI, however, each time I get access denied. There is no firewall between the servers, no hardware or software. The account is a local administrator account, working using RDP - and working from another Windows 2003 server.

The account is a local account, the server is not connected to a domain.

However, from Windows 2008 I get "Access Denied". Besides firewall and lack of credentials, which is not an issue, what other setting might be causing this?

Best Regards,
Anders

Comment: How are you connecting? (powershell, vbscript, some WMI tool?)  What are you specifying for your impersonationLevel and authenticationLevel?

Comment: @SimonCatlin Cheers mate for the comment and additional questions. However, I got it working, see answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not like answering my own questions but a solution was found, the authentication level. The Windows 2003 server as forcefully requesting NTLM2 while Windows 2008 was sending NTLM.

A change in the "LAN Authentication"-parameter in the local polices made it work.